# URI.open fails getting reddit JSON (error 429)

Tags: json, ruby, api, reddit, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to get some JSON data from a subreddit with Ruby; but it fails, returning a 429 error.

```
  begin
    request = URI.open(
      'https://www.reddit.com/r/vintageobscura.json',
      {
      "User-Agent"=>"web:myapp:v1.0.0 (by /u/myusername)"
      }
    );
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => error
    response = error.io
    raise StandardError.new sprintf('Error while opening document: %s',response.status)
    #puts response.string
  end
end
```

It works when I load the URL in my browser; and as you see, I have a user-agent defined as per their [API rules](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API#rules).

Any idea of why it fails ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means "too many requests" – you probably exceed their rate limit. Monitor the `X-Ratelimit` HTTP headers as mentioned in the API rules.

Comment: @Stefan Not sure this is the problem, since it works within my browser... ?

Comment: What do the `X-Ratelimit` headers say, are you above the limit?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how do I check that ?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 429 means Too Many Requests. Reddit API limits clients, crawlers and scrapers.

[image]

There are three response headers you can use to check the rate limiting status. Here is [the documentation](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API#rules).

- X-Ratelimit-Used: Approximate number of requests used in this period
- X-Ratelimit-Remaining: Approximate number of requests left to use
- X-Ratelimit-Reset: Approximate number of seconds to end of period

```
require "open-uri"

URI.open(
  'https://www.reddit.com/r/vintageobscura.json',
  "User-Agent"=>"web:myapp:v1.0.0 (by /u/myusername)"
) { |f| pp f.meta }

# {
#   "x-ratelimit-remaining"=>"289",
#   "x-ratelimit-used"=>"11",
#   "x-ratelimit-reset"=>"125",
#   ...
# }
```

The [Shopify/limiter gem](https://github.com/Shopify/limiter) can help your code wait a certain time after requesting again. Or you can implement this waiting mechanism on your own, using the headers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up using oAuth and requesting a token each time.
Could probably be improved, but it works :

```
def get_access_token()
  puts "getting reddit access token"
  begin
    resp = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
      user: @client_id,
      password: @client_secret,
      payload: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
    response = JSON.parse(resp.body)
    response['access_token']
  rescue StandardError => e
    raise StandardError.new 'Error getting Reddit OAuth2 token.'
  end
end

def get_json(subreddit_slug){
  
  url = sprintf('https://oauth.reddit.com/r/%s.json',subreddit_slug);

  token = get_access_token()
  
  options=>{
    'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token}",
    "User-Agent" => "ruby:#{APP_NAME}:v#{APP_VERSION} (by /u/#{REDDIT_USER})"
  }
  request = URI.open(url,options);
  request.read
}
```